# Can a JAR be signed such that macOS will accept it?

Tags: java, macos

I have an executable JAR which I wish my macOS users to execute from Finder without any command-clicks, or configuration of the system security.

When the JAR is opened it Finder it presents the message:

```
“blah.jar” is from an unidentified developer. Are you sure you want to open it?
```

The JAR is signed though evidently not to Apple's requirements. Can anyone point me at a means of signing the JAR to placate Finder?

I am aware of `javapackager` but ideally don't want to build a separate deliverable for one operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a distinct way to register yourself respectively your deliverables, see [Developer ID](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/). But right on the first page, it says:

> A Developer ID certificate lets Gatekeeper verify that you’re a trusted developer when a user opens your app, plug-in, or installer package downloaded from outside the Mac App Store.

Note: it talks about *apps*, *plug-ins*, or *installers*.

Given the fact that Apple and MacOs are really not known for enthusiastic support of Java, my *gut feeling* is that signing JAR files isn't something they care about.

In other words: I very much doubt that you can convince MacOs to accept and run JAR files.

Comment: Although it is difficult to find hard evidence of it, it is likely true that you can't get rid of the nag question when you deliver only a jar.